# Why can this lifetime not outlive the closure?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am chasing [a compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53420) and found the following [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0bac77f145c4ebfc5e3079947c58de77&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
trait Lt<'a> {
    type T;
}

impl<'a> Lt<'a> for () {
    type T = &'a ();
}

fn test() {
    let _: fn(<() as Lt<'_>>::T) = |_: &'static ()| {};
}

fn main() {
    test();
}
```

I expect the above to compile as I gave a hint for `Lt<'_>` to be `Lt<'static>` and so everything should be fine, but I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:10:53
   |
10 |     let _: fn(<() as Lt<'_>>::T) = |_: &'static ()| {};
   |                                                     ^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 10:36...
  --> src/main.rs:10:36
   |
10 |     let _: fn(<() as Lt<'_>>::T) = |_: &'static ()| {};
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected Lt<'_>
              found Lt<'_>
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &()
              found &'static ()
```

What is the logic behind "first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2"?  As I am looking at a variation of a bug, if the reason is not solid we can attempt to fix it.

## Working variation

```
fn test() {
    let _: fn(<() as Lt<'static>>::T) = |_: &'_ ()| {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code fragments below are a semplification of your case, it helped me to understand
the issue about the compilation error when using the `'static` lifetime declaration in your code.

```
struct Foo {
}

fn _test_ok() {

    // myf is declared as a function pointer that accepts
    // a reference with some generic lifetime  
    let myf: fn(&'_ Foo);

    // with this definition ...
    myf = |_arg: &'_ Foo| {};

    // this local value works as expected
    let local_foo: Foo = Foo {};

    myf(&local_foo);
}

fn _test_static_fail() {

    let myf: fn(&'_ Foo);

    // suppose this myf() definition ...
    myf = |_arg: &'static Foo| {};

    // this local value is compatible with myf() declaration ...
    let local_foo: Foo = Foo {};

    // so theoretically it is usable here: 
    myf(&local_foo);

    // but this is clearly not possible because the anomymous lifetime region where 
    // local_foo lives does not outlive the 'static lifetime required
    // when defining myf()   
}


static FOO: Foo = Foo {};

fn _test_static_flipped() {

    // As you have already discovered
    let myf: fn(&'static Foo) = |arg: &'_ Foo| {};

    // this works because ...
    // 1. FOO is a static value and it is compatible with myf() definition and
    // 2. 'static lifetime outlives every other lifetime  
    myf(&FOO);
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: This depend on the fact that `fn(&'_ Foo)` is always desugared to `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo)`, not `fn(&'somelifetime Foo)` where `'somelifetime` is in scope. This is where my confusion came from.

Comment: In general, I expect in `fn(&'_ Foo)` the anonymous lifetime `'_` to be lower bounded like in this case `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo) where 'a: 'static`, which effectively eliminate confusions like this.

Comment: If so then it seems that `'static` is not included in the lifetime set defined by `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo)`. am I wrong?

Comment: Right now, Rust do not support those things. We can have either `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo)` or `fn(&'a Foo)` where `'a` is in scope. But there is no way to include the lifetime bound like I wrote above...

Comment: `'static` IS included in `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo)`, but the problem is that `fn(&'static Foo)` accepts ONLY `&'static`, so it accepts only a subset of `for<'a> fn(&'a Foo)` allows. That is the problem. What I expected is the type inference to be able to restrict the set `fn(&'_ Foo)` accepts, so they can match.

Comment: For sure I missing something. If `'static` is included in `for<'a>` why [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=00a29ef2b0f50d050176b59ce256ee83&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) does not compile?

Comment: This is because to cast the right hand side value to the left hand side type, the function type in right hand MUST accept a wider range of input, not narrower, to ensure you can never pass an argument to the function that it cannot handle. In this case, `for<'a>` is wider, and `'static` is narrower...